# How to tell shell command tail not to wait for parameter

Tags: linux, shell, tail

My current code

```
tail -n 1 `ls -1t /path/*.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 1` | awk '{print $1}'
```

works fine if there is at least one `*.txt` file in directory.

But if there is no such file, `tail` is waiting for input and does not end.

How do I need to modify my code to ensure it will ends even if no file is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick test, adding `/dev/null` as a "fake" file seems to do the trick.

```
tail -n 1 `ls -1t /path/*.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 1` /dev/null | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Great tip. To make it work `tail -qn 1` instead of `tail -n 1` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put a  timeout on the read, something like this:-

```
tail -f *.txt | read -t 30 line
```

or this:-

```
if [ -f /path/*.txt ]; then 
   tail -n 1 `ls -1t /path/*.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 1` | awk '{print $1}'
fi
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Works fine in ksh. Please test.

Answer (score -1):

A simple if statement to check if the file exists is probably the best and least obfuscated way to do it. 
ksh:

```
if [ -f /path/*.txt ]; then 
    tail -n 1 `ls -1t /path/*.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 1` | awk '{print $1}'
fi
```

Adding **bash syntax** which is differenent

```
files=(f/path/*.txt)
if [ -f ${files[0]} ];
    tail -n 1 `ls -1t /path/*.txt 2>/dev/null | head -n 1` | awk '{print $1}'
fi
```